# Design Pattern - Abstract Factory Pattern Implementation in PHP

Tags: php, object-oriented, abstract-factory

#### Products Class that are like

Table, Chair, etc.

Please review it and give your thoughts and let me know if there are any rooms for improvement.

#### Products.php

```
<?php

abstract class Products
{

}

class Table extends products
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        echo "New Table Created";
    }
}

class Chair extends products
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        echo "New Chair Created";
    }
}
```

#### Factory Class That can produce Plastic Furniture, Wooden Furniture

##### Abstract Factory Class - FurnitureClass

```
<?php
include "products.php";

abstract class FurnitureFactory
{
    abstract function building();
}

class WoodenFactory extends FurnitureFactory
{
    const TABLE = 1;
    const CHAIRS = 2;

    public function building()
    {
        echo "Building Wooden Furniture";
    }

    public function makeWoodenTable()
    {
        echo "Wooden ";
        return new Table();
    }

    public function makeWoodenChair()
    {
        echo "Wooden ";
        return new Chair();
    }
}

class PlasticFactory extends FurnitureFactory
{
    public function building()
    {
        echo "Building Plastic Furniture";
    }
}

$wfactory = new WoodenFactory();
$wtable = $wfactory->makeWoodenTable();
$wchair - $wfactory->makeWoodenChair();
```

Comment: seems to be redundant in case if some factory should build a furniture set which is comprised of 1 table and 2 chairs

Comment: imho, having a `WoodenFactory` where you have to call `makeWooden...` methods, is not entirely how you would like your factory. A `makeTable` and `makeChair` will make more sence. Then every `furnitureFactory` can have a `makeTable` and `makeChair`, changing the factory from Wooden to Plastic just produces different objects. (instead of also changing the method calls)

Answer (score 1):

The class `Products` seems better named as `Product` (singular) since a *table* is a type of *product*, as is a *chair*.

---

The methods in `WoodenFactory` could simply be static methods since they don't appear to depend on any state, and thus the word `wooden` could be removed from them - e.g. `WoodenFactory::makeTable()` and `WoodenFactory::makeChair()`.

---

The constants `TABLE` and `CHAIRS` don't appear to be used for anything...